# Reading multiple files using BufferedReader

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader

I want to read texts from two or more files using a single BufferedReader object.

This is how I did it in my code.

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
Path p1 = Paths.get("sum1.csv");

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(p1, charset);
try {
    String line;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null && !line.isEmpty()){
        list.add(line);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", e);
    reader.close();
}

Path p2 = Paths.get("sum2.csv");
reader = Files.newBufferedReader(p2, charset);
try {
    String line;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null && !line.isEmpty()){
        list.add(line);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", e);
    reader.close();
}
```

The code compiled and run correctly.

What is the standard way to deal with this problem? Is it possible to read two or more files using a single BufferedReader?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
try(
  FileInputStream is1=new FileInputStream("sum1.csv");
  FileInputStream is2=new FileInputStream("sum2.csv");
  SequenceInputStream is=new SequenceInputStream(is1, is2);
  BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, charset));)
{
  try {
      String line;
      while((line = reader.readLine()) != null && !line.isEmpty()){
          list.add(line);
      }
  } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", e);
  }
}
```

By the way, did you mean

```
String line;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
  if(!line.isEmpty()) list.add(line);
```

for your inner loop? Your code stops at the first empty line, my suggested alternative skips empty lines. But I can only guess your real intention.

Comment: I have somewhat similar scenario. It's just that I have sum1 to sumN, N is a very huge number. How can I read all of them together at a time? Can I do something like sum*?

Comment: @tanmay2507: `SequenceInputStream` has a [constructor that accepts an `Enumeration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/SequenceInputStream.html#SequenceInputStream-java.util.Enumeration-). If you struggle building a solution upon that, open a new question.

Comment: Ugh, I wish there was a way to pass it via lambdas.

Comment: @tanmayghosh2507 is probably looking for `Collections.enumeration(List.of(is1, is2))`

Comment: @SridharSarnobat maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49272713/2711488) helps. Its `StreamInputStream` accepts a `Stream` which you can populate with lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

In the code above, you *did* create a new BufferedReader to read from the second file.  What you've done is perfectly fine, although it would make sense to put the repeated code into a method that takes the filename and the list of strings as arguments.

You've got one little glitch - if there's an empty line in the middle of either of your files, your program stops reading when it gets to it.  I'm not sure if that's actually what you want.

Comment: It seems no way to avoid creating a new BufferedReader to read from the second file. What do you think?

Comment: I certainly don't know of any way to avoid it.  But I also don't know why you would want to avoid it.  Having a new BufferedReader works just fine.