# How to represent an empty InputStream

Tags: java, java-stream, inputstream

I'm reducing a stream of `InputStreams` like so:

```
InputStream total = input.collect(
    Collectors.reducing(
        empty,
        Item::getInputStream, 
        (is1, is2) -> new SequenceInputStream(is1, is2)));
```

For the identity `InputStream`, I'm using:

```
InputStream empty = new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0]);
```

This works, but is there a better way to represent an empty `InputStream`?

Comment: In what way better? What's so bad about using an empty `BAIS`?

Comment: just a thought... you know you can collect your inputStreams to a list and then just do `SequenceInputStream(Collections.enumeration(yourCollectedList)))`?

Comment: @Kayaman Fairly minor, but an extra empty byte array gets created.  I'm mostly interested if I've missed something along the lines of Collections.emptyList().

Comment: FYI, you can replace `(is1, is2) -> new SequenceInputStream(is1, is2)` with `SequenceInputStream::new`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would go a different route.

Reducing a larger number of `InputStream` instances via `(is1, is2) -> new SequenceInputStream(is1, is2)` may create a deep unbalanced tree of `SequenceInputStream` instances, which can become very inefficient.

A linear data structure is more appropriate:

```
InputStream total = new SequenceInputStream(
    Collections.enumeration(input.map(Item::getInputStream).collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

This creates a single `SequenceInputStream` processing all collected input streams. Since this also intrinsically handles the empty list case, there is no need for a special empty `InputStream` implementation anymore.

---

But when you look at [the source code of `SequenceInputStream`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/io/SequenceInputStream.java), you’ll see that this class in no magic, in fact, we could even do better by not using archaic classes like `Vector` and `Enumeration`:

```
public class StreamInputStream extends InputStream {
    final Spliterator<? extends InputStream> source;
    final Consumer<InputStream> c = is -> in = Objects.requireNonNull(is);
    InputStream in;

    public StreamInputStream(Stream<? extends InputStream> sourceStream) {
        (source = sourceStream.spliterator()).tryAdvance(c);
    }
    public StreamInputStream(InputStream first, InputStream second) {
        this(Stream.of(first, second));
    }
    public int available() throws IOException {
        return in == null? 0: in.available();
    }
    public int read() throws IOException {
        if(in == null) return -1;
        int b; do b = in.read(); while(b<0 && next());
        return b;
    }
    public int read(byte b[], int off, int len) throws IOException {
        if((off|len) < 0 || len > b.length - off) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        if(in == null) return -1; else if(len == 0) return 0;
        int n; do n = in.read(b, off, len); while(n<0 && next());
        return n;
    }
    public void close() throws IOException {
        closeCurrent();
    }
    private boolean next() throws IOException {
        closeCurrent();
        return source.tryAdvance(c);
    }
    private void closeCurrent() throws IOException {
        if(in != null) try { in.close(); } finally { in = null; }
    }
}
```

Besides being simpler and cleaner (it doesn’t need statements like `catch (IOException ex) { throw new Error("panic"); }`), it considers the lazy nature of streams: when being closed before all elements have been traversed, it does not traverse the remaining stream to close the `InputStream` elements, as they are normally not even created at this point, thus don’t need to be closed.

The creation of the stream now is as simple as

```
InputStream total = new StreamInputStream(input.map(Item::getInputStream));
```

Comment: oh my I need to try this... we are using the first approach (as I said in the comment), this looks much slicker though

Comment: close to confirmed... this will hit our code base (yet again!) much appreciated

Answer (score 48):

Since Java 11, you could use a static method [`InputStream.nullInputStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#nullInputStream()):

> Returns a new InputStream that reads no bytes. The returned stream is initially open. The stream is closed by calling the close() method. Subsequent calls to close() have no effect.

Comment: Notice that the the `InputStream.nullInputStream()` does not support `mark`, in contrast to `new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0])`.

Comment: fyi: the content of this inputStream are empty string

Answer (score 35):

Since `InputStream` has only one abstract method, [`read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read--),

> `public abstract int read() throws IOException`
>
> **Returns:**
>   the next byte of data, or `-1` if the end of the stream is reached.

it is easy to create an empty stream by an [anonymous subclass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).
Like this:

```
InputStream empty = new InputStream() {
    @Override
    public int read() {
        return -1;  // end of stream
    }
};
```

But admittedly, it is more code than your empty `ByteArrayInputStream`.

Comment: this is smart (for me at least), 1+

Answer (score 1):

If you have Apache `commons-io` in your project:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

IOUtils.toInputStream("")
```

Comment: This usage is deprecated!

Comment: @yusuf it's deprecated in favour of a newer version of this method that you can find from docs and use

Comment: Replacement to deprecated method IOUtils.toInputStream("", StandardCharsets.UTF_8))