# read all files and write their contents into one file

Tags: java, java-stream

How do I read all the files and write their contents into one file?
Is it possible to do this using Files.walk?

```
Path pathDir = Path.of("files_STREAM_Lesson7");
    if (!Files.exists(pathDir)) {
        Files.createDirectory(pathDir);
    }
    Path pathDir1 = Path.of("files_STREAM_Lesson7/newDIR");
    if (!Files.exists(pathDir1)) {
        Files.createDirectory(pathDir1);
    }


    Path pathFile1 = Path.of("files_STREAM_Lesson7/Lesson7NIO1.txt");
    if (!Files.exists(pathFile1)) {
        Files.createFile(pathFile1);
    }
    Path pathFile2 = Path.of("files_STREAM_Lesson7/newDIR/Lesson7NIO2.txt");
    if (!Files.exists(pathFile2)) {
        Files.createFile(pathFile2);
    }
    Path pathFile3 = Path.of("files_STREAM_Lesson7/newDIR/Lesson7NIO3.txt");
    if (!Files.exists(pathFile3)) {
        Files.createFile(pathFile3);
    }

    Path path = Paths.get("files_STREAM_Lesson7");
```

//       Stream walk = Files.walk(path).filter(Files::isRegularFile).map(Files::readAllLines);

Comment: Try to find out how to copy *one* file. Then expand the solution to handle multiple files.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
    // ....

    Path path = Paths.get("files_STREAM_Lesson7");
    try (Stream<Path> walk = Files.walk(path)) {
        walk.filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                .flatMap(this::getLines)
                .forEach(this::fillOutputFile);
    }

}

private Stream<String> getLines(Path path) {
    try {
        return Files.lines(path);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
}

private void fillOutputFile(String line) {
    Path outputFile = Path.of("outputFile.txt");

    try {
        Files.writeString(
                outputFile,
                line + System.lineSeparator(),
                StandardOpenOption.APPEND
        );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: the compiler swears at (this::getline)

Comment: @RZav Your code is in `public static void main(String[] args) {...}` ?

Comment: If you don’t care about performance, you can call `Files.writeString` for every line. But the minimum you have to do to make this useful, is to specify the `StandardOpenOption.APPEND` option.

Comment: It is simpler to create an `OutputStream` for the destination file, and is the `InputStream::transferTo` method to copy data from an input stream to that output stream. Though you might need to write some separator between files.

Comment: @Youcef LAIDANI yes

Comment: @RZav try to replace this:: by `YourClassName className = new YourClassName();` `className::getLines`

Comment: @MarkRotteveel or, since the starting point is a stream of `Path`, invoke [`Files.copy(Path source, OutputStream out)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,java.io.OutputStream)) for each element. But the principle is the same, just create a single target `OutputStream` for the entire operation…

Comment: (Which is what the `SequenceInputStream` approach uses vvvv)

Comment: @Youcef LAIDANI to file "outputFile.txt " only the contents of the file are recorded "Lesson7NIO3.txt "

Comment: @Youcef LAIDANI  `Files.writeString(outputFile, line + System.lineSeparator(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);` I added an option, now it works

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a `SequenceInputStream`. Generally speaking, when you're copying text files (in this case we find all.txt files in the tree [narrow the pattern as necessary] from the directory given as the argument to the app and write them into one file), you often don't need to invoke ops that will parse them into lines, as that's a needless inefficiency.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.SequenceInputStream;

public class Finder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            List<InputStream> allTextStreams = Files.find(Path.of(args[0]), Integer.MAX_VALUE, (p,a) ->p.toString().endsWith(".txt")).
                map(Finder::mapPathToInputStream).
                collect(Collectors.toList());
            try (SequenceInputStream seqIn = new SequenceInputStream(Collections.enumeration(allTextStreams));
                OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(Path.of("all-files.text"))) {
                seqIn.transferTo(out);
            }
        }
        catch(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static InputStream mapPathToInputStream(Path p) {
        InputStream result = null;
        try {
            result = Files.newInputStream(p);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: When you have a `Stream` of `InputStream`, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49272713/2711488) might be interesting. Though you can also just call [`Files.copy(Path source, OutputStream out)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,java.io.OutputStream)) for each `Path` without dealing with `InputStream` manually.

Comment: @Holger are you saying that `InputStream` is faster than `File.copy` or `Files.WriteString`?

Comment: @RZav not even remotely. And I don’t see how any of my posts could be interpreted that way.